# Generación de reportes en Excel desde Java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Tengo un problema, estoy generando reportes desde una base de datos que tengo en un servidor, todo va bien cuando son pocos registros, pero cuando ya son bastantes se tarda mucho, pero logra generarlo, se supone que el proceso debe ser rápido, pero no encuentro la manera de solucionarlo, les dejo mi código:

```
        File archivo = new File("ReporteDeProductos.xlsx");

    // Creamos el libro de trabajo de Excel formato OOXML
    Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

    // La hoja donde pondremos los datos
    Sheet pagina = workbook.createSheet("Productos");

    // Creamos el estilo paga las celdas del encabezado
    CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
    // Indicamos que tendra un fondo azul aqua
    // con patron solido del color indicado
    style.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.TURQUOISE.getIndex());
    style.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
    //Aqui se pone al centro el tetxo
    style.setAlignment(HSSFCellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
    //Aqui ponemos la fuente
    org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Font font = workbook.createFont();
    font.setBold(true);
    font.setFontName("Arial");
    style.setFont(font);

    // style.setShrinkToFit(true);
    String[] titulos = {"ID", "MARCA", "CAMPAÑA", "SUCURSAL", "LINEA", "CODIGO DE BARRAS", "REFERENCIA", "PRODUCTO", "TEMPORADA", "COLOR", "TALLA", "CANTIDAD", "PCZ", "PCZ+I.V.A.", "PPZ", "PRECIO MAYORISTA", "PRECIO SOCIOS", "PRECIO EMPLEADOS", "CODIGO ZOUI"};

    // Creamos una fila en la hoja en la posicion 0
    Row fila = pagina.createRow(0);

    // Creamos el encabezado
    for(int i = 0; i < titulos.length; i++) {
        // Creamos una celda en esa fila, en la posicion
        // indicada por el contador del ciclo
        Cell celda = fila.createCell(i);

        // Indicamos el estilo que deseamos
        // usar en la celda, en este caso el unico
        // que hemos creado
        celda.setCellStyle(style);

        celda.setCellValue(titulos[i]);
    }
    CellStyle style1 = workbook.createCellStyle();
    style1.setAlignment(HSSFCellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);

    try{

        ResultSet select = Conexion.conex().prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM Producto WHERE SUCURSAL='"+jcb_sucursal.getSelectedItem().toString()+"'").executeQuery();
        fila = pagina.createRow(1);
        int num=1;
        while(select.next()){
            String[] datos = {select.getString(1), select.getString(2), select.getString(3), select.getString(4), select.getString(5), select.getString(6), select.getString(7), select.getString(8), select.getString(9), select.getString(10), select.getString(11), select.getString(12), select.getString(13), select.getString(14), select.getString(15), select.getString(16), select.getString(17), select.getString(18), select.getString(19)};
            for(int i = 0; i < datos.length; i++) {
                // Creamos una celda en esa fila, en la
                // posicion indicada por el contador del ciclo
                Cell celda = fila.createCell(i);
                pagina.autoSizeColumn(i);

                //Aqui se ajusta al tamaño de la celda
                celda.setCellStyle(style1);

                celda.setCellValue( datos[i] );

            }
            num++;
            fila=pagina.createRow(num);

        }
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Productos no econtrados");

    }

    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Archivos de excel", "xlsx");
    chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
    chooser.setDialogTitle("Guardar archivo");
    chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);
    if (chooser.showSaveDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        // Ahora guardaremos el archivo
        try {
            // Creamos el flujo de salida de datos,
            // apuntando al archivo donde queremos
            // almacenar el libro de Excel
            FileOutputStream salida = new FileOutputStream(chooser.getSelectedFile().toString().concat(".xlsx"));

            // Almacenamos el libro de
            // Excel via ese
            // flujo de datos
            workbook.write(salida);

            // Cerramos el libro para concluir operaciones
            workbook.close();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Archivo creado exitosamente");

        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Archivo no creado");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Error en la salida");
        }
    }
```

Esto solo pasa cuando son varios registros

Gracias por su ayuda

Comment: Identificaste que parte del flujo es la lenta? Sera la consulta sql? La creación del Workbook en memoria? o la escritura a disco?

Comment: Según yo es la escritura al archivo, ya que al momento de insertar cada dato de la consulta le da un formato, pero no encuentro una manera de hacerlo más optimo

Comment: Como te preguntaba @Klaimmore, te recomiendo que identifiques que parte dentro de la ejecución de tu código es la que más afectada se ve cuando son muchos los datos a procesar. Otra cosa, de cuántos datos estamos hablando y que tamaño aproximado tienen estos?

Comment: Según yo la parte afectada es al momento de escribir en el libro, estamos hablando de un aproximado de 2000 registros

Comment: Intenta seguir las sugerencias de este faq: http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10165 también podrias intentar con otro tipo de libro, el HSSF en lugar de XSSF